# Conditional execution of methods based on some static boolean value

Tags: c#

I want to do something like:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
  if (!SomeStaticClass.CanDoWork)
  {
     return;
  }
}

public void DoSomethingElse()
{
  if (!SomeStaticClass.CanDoWork)
  {
     return;
  }

  // ....
}
```

I want to avoid duplication, since this would be present in a lot of class methods.

I tried looking into [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netcore-3.1) but it seems that can't easily fix this issue.
Can this be done by Method attributes, or any other 'easy' way, if there isn't an 'easy' way, since the last approach would be to add an *IF* statement to every method.

Comment: Maybe you can create use factories

Comment: can you give us some more context? are these two methods also called dependent on another condition? On the first glance it seems that you could have a wrapping method that contains this if statement and gets an action as parameter

Answer (score 1):

with the context given by you, the first things that comes to my mind is to make a wrapping method that would contain the if statement. It would get the real method as parameter and excecute it condionally.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ConditionalExcecution(()=> DoSomethingOnlyCode());
    }
    
    private void DoSomethingOnlyCode()
    {
        // here the entire code     
    }

    private void DoSomethingElseOnlyCode()
    {
        // here the entire code     
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        ConditionalExcecution(()=> DoSomethingElseOnlyCode());
    }
    
    private void ConditionalExcecution(Action action)
    {
        if (SomeStaticClass.CanDoWork)
        {
            action();
        }
    }               
}
```

This way you would have the if statement only in 1 place and hide the unconditional method code from the user of your API by private methods.

Depending on your context there might be better solutions to this dilema.